# hide/ remove menu from menuitem

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, hide

I have Joomla menu as below.

```
<li class="level1 parent">
<a href="/www.dd.com/index.php/donations" class="level1 parent">
<span>Donations</span>
</a>
</li>

<li class="level1 parent">
<a href="/www.dd.com/index.php/fund" class="level1 parent">
<span>Fund</span>
</a>
</li>
```

What I am able to do is find the list menu that I have.

```
var texts = [], lis = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var im=lis.length;
var textFound;
for(var i=0; im>i; i++) {
textFound = lis[i].firstChild.nodeValue
  texts.push(lis[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
}
```

What I want to do is `if menu is Donations, hide it`

I tried with `this.style.display='none';`, however it is not working.

```
var texts = [], lis = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var im=lis.length;
var textFound;
for(var i=0; im>i; i++) {
textFound = lis[i].firstChild.nodeValue
  texts.push(lis[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
  this.style.display='none';
}
```

Any idea how to get this done?

### Note, I want this to be done in JAVASCRIPT ONLY. NO JQUERY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `this`, it should be like `lis[i].style.display = 'none'`

Also you will need to compare the text you get.. I don't see any comparision condition to hide specific texts.